# NeatBeans отладка

Tags: java

У меня в проекте несколько классов. я пошагал просматривал как  изменяется те или иные переменные. Хочу также проверить другой класс. но когда делаю "Отладка-Войти" я опять попадаю в предыдущий класс, который я просматривал по шагам. Как переключится?

Comment: Расстреливать надо за такие вопросы...

Comment: qwas13: Это, знаете ли, дао программирования. Вы не можете видеть класс до тех пор, пока Течение Хода Вещей (известное среди западных варваров как execution flow) не подхватит его. Определёнными мистическими практиками (например, _Отладочный Вызов_ или _Unit Test_) начинающие на пути дао смогут возмутить и перенаправить Течение Хода Вещей, но истинномудрый смело глядит в бездну, используя лишь мантру breakpoint.

Смело идите по дороге программирования, истина откроется вам. Не сразу, лет через 7.

Comment: так куда и как ты хочешь войти?, можно пошагать по объекту класса. можешь хотя-бы скинуть кусок кода где ты стоял при отладке, где ты делаешь "Отладка-Войти".

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я не правильно понимаю вопрос, но в чем проблема, почему не поставить брэйк поинт там, где хочешь посмотреть? а потом хоть по шагам, хоть дальше по брякам...